# Simple SSO system like Google Identity Toolkit but without the locked UI?

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

The Google Identity Toolkit is awesome. So clean and easy to set up! Trouble is, it forces you to use its UI, which isn't working for me. Is there anything else out there that will let the visitor click a GMAIL or YAHOO Mail icon to trigger an OpenID (or oAuth2) request, without hijacking the interface?

I've already implemented Facebook Logins in my site, which lets me customize the sign-in button however I want. For example, here's my current sign-in menu (with PHP/AJAX/MySQL site authentication for those who don't want to use their Facebook/etc. account to sign in):

[image]

Clicking FACEBOOK triggers the Facebook JS SDK for the login. Simple enough. I just want a GMAIL logo and YAHOO logo below it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you randomly putting NAMES in CAPITALS?  And you can always use the bare API.  As per OAuth though, you will at the very least have some of the 3rd page design involved in a redirect.

Comment: RANDOM capitals ANNOY the hell out of ME.  Anyway, you can find a lower level API then.  I'm not positive, but there should be APIs out there for PHP for basically any major site.

Comment: The only caps that didn't belong there were used to communicate BUTTONS. I'm a visual thinker, and also hate thoughtless caps, but above they serve a purpose. I've spent 2 days searching for a single example of this API that worked without mangling the interface or totally munging up the codespace. Lots of antiquated and abandoned projects, but not one simple functional example that I could find. If anyone has seen something simple that works well, I'd be grateful to know of it!

Comment: To be blunt, no they don't serve a purpose above. In fact, they distract me from what you're actually trying to say. Anyway, I can't help with a particular library.  Worst case you could drop down to the bare OAuth 2 level.  There should at least be some decently coded libraries for that.

Comment: We communicate differently. Anyways thanks for the thoughts, digging in to the OAuth 2 spec may be the only way. I'm surprised there aren't more examples of simple SSO implementations.

Comment: I suppose so.  And the OAuth 2 spec is quite a beast.  I'd probably try working with even a half-way decent implementation of it before writing one from scratch.  Apparently http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2 is written and maintained by google, so surely it's fairly good.  Anyway, good luck! :)

Comment: Corbin, that was exactly what I was seeking. Took me 10 minutes to implement as I wanted. Post as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Glad you found something that works :).  Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid the UI of a high level library, you're going to have to use a lower level library.  In particular, you're going to need an OAuth 2 library.  There's not that many of them (surprisingly), but your best bet is likely going to be the one authored by google: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution that allows you to leverage all of the APIs for the major ID providers, you might want to test out Janrain Engage.

Here's a quick lowdown on our Engage API endpoints (specifically, auth_info), for social authentication:

http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/api/#Engage

You can have complete control over the UI and display just Google and Yahoo.

http://janrain.com/products/engage/ (for marketing-ese)